# In onPause(), why some methods are not executed if put after the call to super.onPause()?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, lifecycle

This code was printing the log, but returning null to the parent activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Two", "onPause()");
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(TWO_CLICKS_FOR_ONE, mClicks2);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 
}
```

Seems that the Intent was not being created, but the log line was being executed. This ended up inducing a bug, where the parent activity was getting null as value for data. The parent activity uses onActivityResult to retrieve the data:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("One", "onActivityResult()");
    if (data == null) {
        Log.d("One", "data == null !!!");
        return;
    }
    mClicks2 = data.getIntExtra(Two.TWO_CLICKS_FOR_ONE, 0);
    Log.d("One", "mClicks2 = " + mClicks2);
}
```

As I said, data has a null value here, so mClicks2 is never assigned a value.

Things changed when I put the super.onPause() call at the end of the block. Now everything works as expected:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d("Two", "onPause()");
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(TWO_CLICKS_FOR_ONE, mClicks2);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    super.onPause();
}
```

With this code Intent data is instantiated, putExtra() and setResult() are called, and mClicks2 is successfully assigned a value in the parent activity.

What's the reason of this behavior? Log.d() executes after super.onPause(), but the Intent is never instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Because behind the scenes Android processes the result you set with `setResult(RESULT_OK, data);` during the `super.onPause()` call. If you set the result after calling `super.onPause()` you just missed the chance to pass it back to the parent activity, you're too late. You have to comply with the Activity's life-cycle for things to work properly.